# Reading collision force between two bodies in a 3D physics simulation engine (ODE?)

Tags: physics-engine

I want to detect collision and read the collision force vector between two bodies in a 3D physics engine like ODE. Could someone please tell me how to achieve this?

```
#include "ode/ode.h"     
#include "drawstuff/drawstuff.h"  
#define NUM 4         

dWorldID    world;       
dBodyID     link[NUM];    
dJointID      joint[NUM];  
static double THETA[NUM] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }; 
static double l[NUM] = { 0.10, 0.90, 1.00, 1.00 };  
static double r[NUM] = { 0.20, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04 };  
//static dWorldID world;
static dSpaceID space;
static dGeomID  ground;
static dJointGroupID contactgroup;
//dsFunctions fn;
static void nearCallback(void* data, dGeomID o1, dGeomID o2)
{
const int N = 10;
dContact contact[N];

int isGround = ((ground == o1) || (ground == o2));

int n = dCollide(o1, o2, N, &contact[0].geom, sizeof(dContact));
if (isGround) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        contact[i].surface.mode = dContactBounce;
        contact[i].surface.bounce = 0.1; // (0.0~1.0) restitution parameter
        contact[i].surface.bounce_vel = 0.1; // minimum incoming velocity for bounce 
        dJointID c = dJointCreateContact(world, contactgroup, &contact[i]);
        dJointAttach(c, dGeomGetBody(contact[i].geom.g1),
            dGeomGetBody(contact[i].geom.g2));
        //if (contact[i].geom.depth > 0.000001)
        {
            printf("Collision points %d , force %f\n", n, contact[i].geom.depth);
        }
    }
}
}

void control() {  
static int step = 0;     
double k1 = 10.0, fMax = 100.0; 
printf("\r%6d:", step++);
for (int j = 1; j < NUM; j++) {
    double tmpAngle = dJointGetHingeAngle(joint[j]);  
    double z = THETA[j] - tmpAngle;  
    dJointSetHingeParam(joint[j], dParamVel, k1 * z); 
    dJointSetHingeParam(joint[j], dParamFMax, fMax); 
}
```

}

void start() {
float xyz[3] = { 3.04, 1.28, 0.76 };
float hpr[3] = { -160.0, 4.50, 0.00 };
dsSetViewpoint(xyz, hpr);
}

void command(int cmd) {
switch (cmd) {
case 'j':  THETA[1] += 0.05; break;
case 'f':  THETA[1] -= 0.05; break;
case 'k':  THETA[2] += 0.05; break;
case 'd':  THETA[2] -= 0.05; break;
case 'l':  THETA[3] += 0.05; break;
case 's':  THETA[3] -= 0.05; break;
}

```
if (THETA[1] < -M_PI)   THETA[1] = -M_PI; 
if (THETA[1] > M_PI)    THETA[1] = M_PI;
if (THETA[2] < -2 * M_PI / 3)  THETA[2] = -2 * M_PI / 3;
if (THETA[2] > 2 * M_PI / 3)  THETA[2] = 2 * M_PI / 3;
if (THETA[3] < -2 * M_PI / 3)  THETA[3] = -2 * M_PI / 3;
if (THETA[3] > 2 * M_PI / 3)  THETA[3] = 2 * M_PI / 3;
```

}

void simLoop(int pause) {
control();
dWorldStep(world, 0.02);
dSpaceCollide(space, 0, &nearCallback);
dsSetColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
dsDrawCapsuleD(dBodyGetPosition(link[i]), dBodyGetRotation(link[i]), l[i], r[i]);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
dsFunctions fn;
dMass mass;
double x[NUM] = { 0.00 }, y[NUM] = { 0.00 };
double z[NUM] = { 0.05, 0.50, 1.50, 2.55 };
double m[NUM] = { 10.00, 2.00, 2.00, 2.00 };
double anchor_x[NUM] = { 0.00 }, anchor_y[NUM] = { 0.00 };
double anchor_z[NUM] = { 0.00, 0.10, 1.00, 2.00 };
double axis_x[NUM] = { 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00 };
double axis_y[NUM] = { 0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 1.00 };
double axis_z[NUM] = { 1.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00 };
dInitODE2(0);
fn.version = DS_VERSION;  fn.start = &start;
fn.step = &simLoop;      fn.command = &command;
fn.path_to_textures = "../../drawstuff/textures";

```
dInitODE();  
world = dWorldCreate();  
dWorldSetGravity(world, 0, 0, -9.8);     

//world = dWorldCreate();
space = dHashSpaceCreate(0);
contactgroup = dJointGroupCreate(0);
dJointGroupEmpty(contactgroup);
//dWorldSetGravity(world, 0, 0, -0.5);

// Create a ground
ground = dCreatePlane(space, 0, 0, 1, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {       
    link[i] = dBodyCreate(world);     
    dBodySetPosition(link[i], x[i], y[i], z[i]); 
    dMassSetZero(&mass);      
    dMassSetCappedCylinderTotal(&mass, m[i], 3, r[i], l[i]);  
    dBodySetMass(link[i], &mass);  
}

joint[0] = dJointCreateFixed(world, 0); 
dJointAttach(joint[0], link[0], 0);    
dJointSetFixed(joint[0]);               
for (int j = 1; j < NUM; j++) {
    joint[j] = dJointCreateHinge(world, 0); 
    dJointAttach(joint[j], link[j - 1], link[j]); 
    dJointSetHingeAnchor(joint[j], anchor_x[j], anchor_y[j], anchor_z[j]); 
    dJointSetHingeAxis(joint[j], axis_x[j], axis_y[j], axis_z[j]); 
}
dsSimulationLoop(argc, argv, 640, 570, &fn);
dCloseODE();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What you're asking is quite broad, you're asking us to 1) show you how to use a physics engine, 2) show you how to detect collisions and 3) detect the force. Do you know how to use a physics engine? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Presumably you started by researching the published [documentation about how to work with collisions in ODE](http://ode.org/wiki/index.php?title=Manual). Can you show us what you've done so far based on your research, or explain where specifically you're stuck?

Comment: I was working with sketchyphysics in google sketchup but in this case I do not know how to read the collision force vector between two bodies. So now I am looking for a physics engine where I can read the collision force vector between two bodies. I installed ODE and I am trying to work with it.

Comment: What do you need it for? This might help figure out what to tell you.

Comment: I am trying to get the collision force vector from the tip of the robotic arm when ever it collides with the ground or some other object. I have edited my question and added the code that I am working with.

Comment: Ok, and in real life, how would you get that collision force?